# Use value as setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use an HTML value as a number in JavaScript setTimeout function?

For example, my timeout function looks like this:

```
var object = document.getElementById("object");

setTimeout(function(){ 
      object.style.opacity = "0";
    }, 1000);
```

However I want to set the timing to a dynamic value from an HTML input, like this:

```
// HTML:
<input id ="input" type="number" value="1"/>

// JavaScript:    
var object = document.getElementById("object");
var input =  document.getElementById("input");

    setTimeout(function(){ 
      object.style.opacity = "0";
    }, input.value + "000");
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` for the `setTimeout` call, this looks like your problem, since `setTimeout` also accepts a string (it will convert it to an int for you).

Comment: `setTimeout` in your first sample is missing a right parenthesis. Is it in your code as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parseInt` to treat value as a number instead of a string for `setTimeout`.

Also, I would avoid using `object` and `input` as variable names in JavaScript - they are not very descriptive. (Even though, you probably used those only as an examples.)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="myInput" type="number" value="1"/>
<div id="myDiv"><p>Some text</p></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

setTimeout(function(){

   myDiv.style.opacity = "0";

}, parseInt(myInput.value, 10) * 1000); // 1 * 1000 = 1000ms (1 second)
```

Here is also: **[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m5Ym4/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
parseInt(input.value, 10);
```

And of course if your time is in seconds, **multiply by 1000**

Comment: +1 for the **multiply**, but the value doesn't have to be int, see [my comment **here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881095/use-value-as-settimeout#comment34914038_22881150)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you did not convert the string value into a number. And there were a couple of syntax errors as well.

Modify this line of code:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  object.style.opacity = "0";
}, parseInt(input.value + "000"));
```

Comment: The second parameter of a _setTimeout_ will be cast to a _Number_ e.g. `setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, 'foo'), '500')`. Your code currently does nothing with your parsed number?

Answer (score 0):

Cast your input to a variable. Your code is basically concatenating a string value.

```
var timeoutLength = parseInt(input.value, 10) * 1000;
```

Then use it like so.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
      object.style.opacity = "0";
},timeoutLength);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the string to an int. Here's how you can do it:

> ```
> setTimeout(function(){ 
>   object.style.opacity = "0";
> },(parseInt(input.value, 10) * 1000));
> ```

Comment: You should always pass the second argument (radix) to `parseInt`. Also, missing parenthesis.

Comment: @JanDvorak, what if he used `Number()`?

Comment: Fixed parenthesis. But why do need radix, isn't base 10 by default?

Comment: @gat by default it's "autodetect". This has an unfortunate side-effect of treating leading zeroes as octal.

Comment: @gat No. It is often, but not always. It depends on the browser; although these days *most* (but not all!) browsers use base 10 as the default.